Merging three files
I would like your help to check and improve my code (for instance, make it more pythonic as some people say). Right now, it does what i need, but i think it looks awful (specially the merging part).
My code merges the first two columns of 3 files that looks like:



Column A
Column B




name_a
city_z


name_b
city_y



Such that at the end i should have something like:



Column A
file_1
file_2
file_3
match




name_a
city_z
city_m
city_z
0


name_b
city_y
city_y
city_y
1



Notice that ideally, each name should have the same city assigned, but there might be errors. All the files have different size. Aditionally, the size of each file is different.
I really appreacite if you can help me improve how my code looks. (Also, please, here, I wrote the code by memory, and there might be mistakes, please do not mind them)
Best regards.
rute_1 = "rute to the file_1.csv"
rute_2 = "rute to the file_2.csv" 
rute_3 = "rute to the file_3.csv" 

with open(rute_1, "r") as file_1:
    file_1 = csv.reader(file_1, delimiter =";")
    file_1 = pd.DataFrame(file_1).iloc[:[0,1]]

with open(rute_2, "r") as file_2:
    file_2 = csv.reader(file_2, delimiter =";")
    file_2 = pd.DataFrame(file_2).iloc[:[0,1]]

with open(rute_3, "r") as file_1:
    file_3 = csv.reader(file_3, delimiter =";")
    file_3 = pd.DataFrame(file_3).iloc[:[0,1]]

combine_1 = pd.merge(file_1, file_2, how ="outer", indicator = "a")
combine_2 = pd.merge(file_1, file_3, how ="outer", indicator = "b")
combine_3 = pd.merge(file_2, file_3, how ="outer", indicator = "c")

combine_final = pd.merge(combine_1, combine_2, how ="outer")
combine_final = pd.merge(combine_final, combine_3, how ="outer").iloc[list of columns to keep] 

combine_final.columns = (names of the columns)
combine_final.order = (order of the columns)

(Here the code continues by counting number of matches for each pair of files)

if you want help to improve your code, make sure your code works. as it is it makes no sense

what do you mean? of course it works. Its the first thing i said. What you do not understand? Need some clarification?

read.csv doesn't exist maybe pd.read_csv does. file_1 = read.csv(file_1, delimiter =";") as file_1: can't work for many other reasons

Well, as i said at the end: "Also, please, here, I wrote the code by memory, and there might be mistakes, please do not mind them".  But yeah, probably read.csv should have been csv.reader.I will edit it. Thanks. Any other thing?

Your code will not run with CSV data as described in your question. You'll get a TypeError exception when you try to execute pd.DataFrame(file_1).iloc[:[0,1]]

As I said before there might be typos here, but it works. I have already run it and I did not see any TypeError message. What would be your alternative to achieve the same outcome?

The simplest thing I can think of is use functions when you're repeating the same action. For example, you open 3 files using essentially the same code; it'd replace that code with:
def open_file(rute):
    with open(rute, "r") as f:
        f = csv.reader(f, delimiter =";")
        f = pd.DataFrame(f).iloc[:[0,1]]
        return f

file_1 = open_file(rute_1)
file_2 = open_file(rute_2)
file_3 = open_file(rute_3)

You can also write a function or use a for loop for managing the file merging, but that might be a bit overkill for your purposes.
